# Could not process parameters: str(https://help.twitter.com/using-twitter/twitter-supported-browsers), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to make a multi threaded web crawler using python but I'm getting this error!

```
import threading
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

# Function to extract URLs that start with http or https


def extract_urls(url):
    # Make a request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find all the links in the HTML
    links = soup.find_all('a')

    # Extract the URLs that start with http or https
    urls = [link['href'] for link in links if link['href'].startswith(
        'http') or link['href'].startswith('https')]

    # Return the list of URLs
    return urls

# Function to crawl a URL using a separate thread


def crawl(url):
    # Extract the URLs from the given URL
    urls = extract_urls(url)


        # Connect to the database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='',
        database='crawler'
    )

    # Create a cursor
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert the data from the array into the table
    sql_insert_query = 'INSERT INTO my_transport (transport, fee) VALUES (%s, %s)'
    result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, urls)

    # Commit the changes to the database
    conn.commit()

    # Close the connection
    conn.close()
    # Print the URLs
    print(urls)

# Create a new thread for each URL
urls = ['https://www.facebook.com/', 'https://www.twitter.com/']
threads = []
for url in urls:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=crawl, args=(url,))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

---

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(https://help.twitter.com/using-twitter/twitter-supported-browsers),
it must be of type list, tuple or dict

---

I haven't figured out the error, can somebody help me.
New to Python

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The error is : Could not process parameters: it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Answer (score 0):

```
result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, urls)
```

This function accepts a collection as parameter, but you provided only one string.
[MySQL Connector Documentation | executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)

Make sure you are passing a collection.

Comment: I'm trying to insert ['https://help.twitter.com/using-twitter/twitter-supported-browsers', 'https://twitter.com/tos', 'https://twitter.com/privacy', 'https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170514', 'https://legal.twitter.com/imprint.html', 'https://business.twitter.com/en/help/troubleshooting/how-twitter-ads-work.html?ref=web-twc-ao-gbl-adsinfo&utm_source=twc&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=ao&utm_content=adsinfo']

Comment: Are you definitely sure that `extract_urls` always return a list even when it's single string? Can you check on debugger?